# equals not working

Tags: android, string, authentication

I am trying to build a simple login page on android however the `equals()` part is not returning true for some reason therefore when I press the button to login nothing happens. This is my Activity

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button login1;
    TextView display1;
    EditText username2, password2;
    TextView test1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.warningText1);
        username2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
        password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
        test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String u1 = username2.getText().toString();

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (u1.equals("a")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, User.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        }); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: use equalIgnoreCase

Comment: The `String u1 = ...` line needs to go inside the `onClick()` method.

Comment: `equals()` is **case sensitive**. Try `equalsIgnoreCase()`, instead.

Comment: Can you try moving "String u1 = username2.getText().toString();" into the onClick() method?

Comment: I did. still does not work.

Comment: You should try to debug it, for example, by printing u1 value just before "if".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText` code runs before the User has entered anything you will have to move this code

```
String u1 = username2.getText().toString();
```

Inside `onClickListener()` as

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String u1 = username2.getText().toString();
        if (u1.equals("a")) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, User.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I did what everyone suggested. It's still not working :(

Comment: Okay let me continue working on it and I will update my answer if I got a clue

Comment: But my fellow @John do you real want a text from the username instead of password??????? should nt your code look for password and compare instead of username?

Comment: Hey mate, don't bother I figured out the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>     String u1 = username2.getText().toString();
> ```

This `getText().toString()` runs when instantiating the `OnClickListener` and at that point there's nothing in the `EditText`. Move that line inside the `onClick()` so it's executed when clicking.

Comment: Then it seems you need to debug your code to see what the value of `u1` is at runtime, and whether the code is executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help!
I figured out the issue. The text was pre-hardcoded in the XML file.